# string stream issue, i think my code looks good, but it displays weird symbols

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and am following a online tutorial, i have copied this guys code multiple times and cannot figure out what is wrong. it just outputs garbled text.

I am using code::blocks

**This is what it outputs (the link below)**

https://gyazo.com/9c2786ef20fb3878354a72904d126f7e

**My Actual Code**

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.h"

using namespace std;

 int main()
   {
Person person;

cout << person.toString() << endl;


return 0;
}
```

**Person.cpp**

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <sstream>

Person::Person()
{
age = 0;
name = "jeff";

}

string Person::toString(){
stringstream ss;

ss << "Name: ";
ss << name;
ss << "; age: ";
ss << age;


}
```

**Person.h**

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Person{
private:
string name;
int age;

public:
Person();

string toString();

};

#endif // PERSON_H
```

Comment: Turn on warnings in your compiler. It will tell you what's wrong here (a non-void function without a return statement.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had two problems with your code.  You were never returning a value and also you should using `stringstream.str()`:

```
int main()
{
    Person person;

    cout << person.toString() << endl;

    return 0;
}

string Person::toString() {
    stringstream ss;

    ss << "Name: ";
    ss << name;
    ss << "; age: ";
    ss << age;

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more clear to leave `toString` as returning a `string` and moving the `rdbuf` inside the function.(or maybe call `str` instead).

Comment: ahh, there we go simply adding **return ss.str();** was able to fix this error.

Comment: now that i look back at the tutorial the guy had, i see he also had that and i left it out.

Comment: best answer to you!